# Skunk Water Formula

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was reading about Skunk Water (a "good"  measure from a policing perspective as a method for crowd dispersion). I would like to find out if anyone has any idea as to the chemical composition of Skunk Water.

The official line is that it's composed from water, yeast, bicarbonate soda and other ingredients, however I have a suspicion that the soda is a red herring since it's also used to counteract the smell of actual skunk spray.

Comment: Fermenting any organic matter, especially the one rich in nitrogen and sulfur, should give you a cheap and effective malodorant. The original Skunk Water composition is a trade secret.

Comment: The sodium bicarbonate is to maintain the pH at a level where the yeast can produce the odor causing substances http://www.skunk-skunk.com/image/users/121755/ftp/my_files/MSDS_Skunk.pdf?id=3225191

Comment: Could just use this conveniently canned food: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surstr%C3%B6mming.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good looking list: [The chemistry of Skunk Spray](http://users.humboldt.edu/wfwood/chemofskunkspray.html)

However, many [stink bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stink_bomb) are commonly made of a very simple molecule called [ammonium sulfide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IHt_H2j7H0).

But if it were up me (in a war), I might be tempted to use [cadaverine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4D5aTNYalQ) and [putrescine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAldEzWpr_A), for that long-term, never-come-back-to-the-area kind of smell.

Now, I know that this is a chemistry forum, but I think it's important to note that there are some bacteria (like *Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron*, *Hafnia alvei*, and S*erratia liquefaciens*, to name a few examples) which produce many of these stinky molecules, and I beleive that proper inoculation of a drum of eggs, would be a very simple, low-tech way to produce a [putrefied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putrefaction) product (that would certainly make me run away).

However, I would very much advise against any sort of assult as you may find yourself in prison or worse for manufacturing or using chemical or biological weapons.

And there's always tear gas ([chloroacetone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_34666573&feature=iv&src_vid=V4D5aTNYalQ&v=DDqIzxTGc78)) and [pepper spray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQIMLEwQWL0) which  are commonly used by police and in warfare.

Other notable compounds include [skatole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZ56LDCABrA), [hydrogen sulphide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRtsexmFO4s), [mercaptans/thiols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanethiol), and other organic sulfoxides; dimethyl sulfoxide is comparatively weak but has a certain savory robustness that really adds a natural tinge to whatever smells bad. A bit of [garlic essential oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diallyl_disulfide) goes a long way.

Comment: Did you mean cadaverine and putrescine? I worked with those compounds, they are not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Butanoic acid smells like skunk (both the animal and cannabis).  Foxes have a similar smell.  Butanoic acid used to be made by the action of the bacteria in cheese on sucrose.  It wouldn't have to be too concentrated to make you smell awful.  Sodium carbonate is used to neutralise the smell (sodium butanoate).  When I worked in a school chemistry department, we used it - very carefully - to make ethyl butanoate, which smells like pineapple.